# Which way efficient to cut from associated array first + last elemets(key + value)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Which way efficient to cut from  associated array first + last elemets(key + value).

(Can be use just unset, but array_pop/array_shift/array_slice not working on associated array)

Example:

input array:

```
$input=array(20=>'v1', 56=>'v2', 80=>'v3',88=>'v4');
```

output array:

```
$input=array( 56=>'v2', 80=>'v3');
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would the functions you suggest not work on associative arrays?

Comment: How are `array_pop` and `array_shift` not working?

Comment: please give example if this functions works

Comment: Manual says that "All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched." While Yosef uses "random" integers as keys (i.e., `20,56,80,88` rather than `0,1,2,3`), they're still "numerical keys", so they get converted to `0,1,2,...`.

Comment: `array_slice()` works just fine, if `$preserve_keys` (4th argument) is set to `true`

Comment: `array_pop()` preserves keys. `array_shift()` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_slice()` is the way to go:

```
$input = array(20=>'v1', 56=>'v2', 80=>'v3',88=>'v4');
$output = array_slice($input, 1, -1, true);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [56] => v2
    [80] => v3
)
```

Don't forget to specify `true` as 4th argument, otherwise keys won't be preserved (i.e., you'll get `0,1,2,...` as keys).

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array_slice($a, 1, -1, true);
```

(Yes this works on associative arrays.)